# Input inside form array is bugged

Tags: angular, forms

[Stackblitz example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-form-array-example)

Why when I start typing into the input, it bugs and loses focus? Furthermore, I can't type more than 4 symbols. Can you help, please?

Comment: the answer mark as ok is incorrect. The answer is not loop over form.constrols.credentials?.value, else form.get('credentials').controls (or form.controls.credentials.controls).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to iterate over each form control instance provided by the aliases form array instance (Source: [docs](https://angular.io/guide/reactive-forms#step-4-displaying-the-form-array-in-the-template)). You are iterating over the value of the credentials form control.

Try looping over `form.get('credentials').controls` instead

```
<div formArrayName="credentials" *ngFor="let creds of form.get('credentials').controls; let i = index">
  <ng-container [formGroupName]="i">
    <input placeholder="Username" formControlName="username">
    <input placeholder="Password" formControlName="password">
  </ng-container>
</div>
```